# MVC2 ViewData Problems

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to pass a list of a few items to a view via the ViewData to create a drop down list.  This shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm new to MVC, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

The controller assigns the list to the ViewData:

```
ViewData["ImageLocatons"] = new SelectList(gvr.ImageLocations);
```

and the view tries to render it into a drop down list:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Location", ViewData["ImageLocations"] as SelectList) %>
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:
*There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Location'.*

Any ideas why this isn't working?  Also, shouldn't it be looking for the key "ImageLocations" rather than location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use:

```
ViewData["Location"] = new SelectList(gvr.ImageLocations);
```

and

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Location") %>
```

Your life will be a lot easier.

Also check out the typo (missing `i`) when setting the ViewData in your example (ImageLocatons => ImageLocations). This causes the second parameter you pass to DropDownList to be `null`. This will cause the MVC engine to search for Location.

Comment: Wow.  I had a spelling error.  I'm using the other method you suggested now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice catch.  +1 for seeing the typo.  I had to re-read a few times even after you pointed it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your ViewData was reset?

Try putting a break point in your View on the line where you emit the drop down list.
Then do a quick watch on ViewData["ImageLocations"].

Make sure that there is a value here when the view tries to use it.